# Something similar to distkey and sort key

Tags: data-warehouse

can anyone explain functions similar to distkey and sortkey which i can use in datawarehouse, or any examples and sources which I can use, any sources or examples will be helpfull.

Comment: Please clarify what are you referring to - what are distkey and sortkey? You mean a distinct id and a column to sort by? Also, include the tag with database server that you are using (e.g. sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

DISTKEY and SORTKEY are specific to AWS Redshift. DISTKEY controls how data is distributed across the nodes in the Redshift cluster, and SORTKEY is a form of indexing specific columns.

On Azure SQL Data Warehouse DISTKEY maps to the WITH (DISTRIBUTION = ?) clause of the CREATE TABLE statement. DISTKEY EVEN maps to ROUND_ROBIN, DISTKEY  maps to HASH() and there is no equivalent to DISTKEY ALL>

SQL Server Parallel Data Warehouse is very similar to Azure SQL Data Warehouse, except DISTKEY ALL maps to REPLICATE.

On both platforms, indexing (including a clustered columnstore index) replace the SORTKEY functionality.

Snowflake Elastic Data Warehouse manages to get great performance without having to worry about these concepts.